# Logging from AppleScript in Automator

Tags: applescript, automator, logs

I am writing an AppleScript (*Run AppleScript* item) from within an application in Apple Automator, but the *Log* panel at the bottom of the window does not display any logged messages (that is, anything logged using the `log ...` AppleScript command). Is there something I'm missing as to how this should work?

Comment: The `Run AppleScript` action doesn’t have a log.  If you are you taking about the `Results` pane, that just shows the output from the script.

Comment: The pane is labelled “Log”, but maybe... Anyway, how do I output to the log in this case?

Comment: You would need to write to a file or display a dialog or whatever - the `Run AppleScript` action does not have a log view.

Comment: I see; that’s rather unfortunate, but thanks for the clarification.